# How to combine the text node of 2 pieces of extracted data using Goutte/Domcrawler

Tags: php, goutte, domcrawler

I've been trying to figure out how to combine two pieces of extracted text into a single result (array). In this case, the title and subtitle of a variety of books.

```
<td class="item_info">
  <span class="item_title">Carrots Like Peas</span>
  <em class="item_subtitle">- And Other Fun Facts</em>
</td>
```

The closest I've been able to get is:

```
$holds = $crawler->filter('span.item_title,em.item_subtitle');
```

Which I've managed to output with the following:

```
$holds->each(function ($node) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print $node->text();
    echo '</pre>';
});
```

And results in

```
<pre>Carrots Like Peas</pre>
<pre>- And Other Fun Facts</pre>
```

Another problem is that not all the books have subtitles, so I need to avoid combining two titles together.
How would I go about combining those two into a single result (or array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I took a roundabout way to get where I wanted to be. I stepped back one level in the DOM to the `td` tag and grabbed everything and dumped it into the array.

I realized that DomCrawler's documentation had the example code to place the text nodes into an array.

```
$items_out = $crawler->filter('td.item_info')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    return $node->text();   
});
```

I'd tried to avoid capturing the `td` because author's were also included in those cells. After even more digging, I was able to strip the authors from the array with the following:

```
foreach ($items_out as &$items) {
    $items = substr($items,0, strpos($items,' - by'));
}
```

Just took me five days to get it all sorted out. Now onto the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

As per [Goutte Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte#more-information), Goutte utilizes the Symfony DomCrawler component.  Information on adding content to a DomCrawler object can be found at[Symfony DomCrawler - Adding Content](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#adding-the-content)